# Python vs PHP speed

Tags: php, python

I want to solve a problem from [Project Euler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Euler) (BTW, problem 25), and I found a solution in Python:

```
fibonacci = 1
old1 = 0
old2 = 1
limit = 1000

i = 1

while len(str(fibonacci)) < limit:
    fibonacci = old1 + old2
    old1 = old2
    old2 = fibonacci
    i = i + 1

print(i)
```

It took 1.5 seconds to calculate.

I implemented the same in PHP, this is the code:

```
$fibonacci = 1;
$old1 = 0;
$old2 = 1;
$limit = 1000;

$i = 1;

while (strlen((string)$fibonacci) < $limit){
    $fibonacci = $old1 + $old2;
    $old1 = $old2;
    $old2 = $fibonacci;
    $i = $i + 1;
}
print($i);
```

And it took more than 30 minutes, and still calculating...

I know that Python is considered faster than PHP, but still it shouldn't be so big a difference. How to improve my PHP code to get the results faster, if there is a way to do it?

**EDIT:**

I edit this post based on comments below so first my solution was not going to work.
One solution can be instead of old while to put this one:

```
while (strlen(number_format($fibonacci, 0, '', '')) < $limit){ ... }
```

But again is a big speed issue.

So the final solution is using [BCMath](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php):

```
$fibonacci = '1';
$old1 = '0';
$old2 = '1';
$limit = 1000;

$i = 1;

while (strlen($fibonacci) < $limit){

    $fibonacci = bcadd($old1, $old2);
    $old1 = $old2;
    $old2 = $fibonacci;
    $i = $i + 1;
}
echo $fibonacci . "<br />";
print($i);
```

So you can get the results at the same speed as Python in PHP.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Definitely, the PHP is going into an infinite loop. There's no way it could be taking that long if there wasn't something wrong...

I don't think counting the digits of these numbers with `strlen` is going to work in PHP. PHP is dealing with the numbers in scientific notation, in lower precision than Python.

I added debugging `echo` statements to PHP, to print out $fibonacci and $i for each step.

A typical Python line looks like

```
fib is 7540113804746346429
i is 92
```

In PHP, that's

```
fib is 7.54011380475E+18
i is 92
```

To accomplish this in PHP, you'll probably need to use a higher precision math library.

Check out http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php - you can use the `bcadd` function to accomplish the addition, and it will work as it does in Python.

Answer (score 6):

It isn't a speed issue, it's a logic problem in the while condition for termination.

It's probably not going to finish. When you convert the current value of $fibonacci to a string in your while test, it will be converted to scientific format and truncated to a limited set of decimal places (dependent on your precision setting) when you cast it to string. That number of digits will be a lot less than 1000, so the while termination condition won't ever be met.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is, that you are working with big numbers. You should use BC Math Functions ([php.net/bc](http://php.net/bc)). So your code can be:

```
$fibonacci = "1";
$old1 = "0";
$old2 = "1";
$limit = 1000;

$i = 1;

while (strlen($fibonacci) < $limit){
    $fibonacci = bcadd($old1, $old2);
    $old1 = $old2;
    $old2 = $fibonacci;
    $i = $i + 1;
}
print($i);
```

I have tried it and it takes about 0.095s.

Answer (score 3):

Many of project Euler problems will have to handle big numbers.
PHP will make your big numbers look like `2.579234678963E+12` which is the Exponential representation of the number... It's obviously hard to work with. 
So, for most of problems, it's best to go with [BCMath Functions](http://php.net/bc). This will keep your number as it is, even if it is a giant number.

Note that using `echo bcmul(500,500);` will never be as fast as `echo 500*500`. And, BCMath function return values are always strings.

To fix your problem replace all arithmetic operations with the corresponding BCMath function.

Answer (score 2):

Since the problem seems to be with converting to strings, here's a much faster way to do it that doesn't require it. This is essentially the same algorithm as you have posted (so I don't feel bad showing it to you) but demonstrates how to use division to test the length of an integer instead of converting it to a string.

```
def fibonacci_digits(limit):
    limit = 10**limit
    fib = 1
    old1 = 0
    old2 = 1

    i = 1
    size = 1
    while size < limit:
        fib = old1 + old2
        if not size//fib:  # // is pythons integer division operator, not a comment
            size *= 10
        old1 = old2
        old2 = fib
        i += 1

    return i

print fibonacci_digits(1000)
```

Converting to a string is slow and is almost never the right thing to do. Here's the timeit results:

```
$ python -mtimeit -s'import fib' 'fib.fibonacci_digits(1000)'
10 loops, best of 3: 30.2 msec per loop

$ python -mtimeit -s'import fib' 'fib.fibonacci_digits2(1000)'
10 loops, best of 3: 1.41 sec per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

I optimized a bit the Python code. Using len(str()) to check the number of digits is very slow. Replaced by math.log10 run your program much faster

***The first term in the Fibonacci sequence to contain 1000 digits is : 4782
Calculated in 0.008573 seconds***

```
import time
from math import log10


def digits(n): # Return the number of digits for n>=1
    return int(log10(n))+1

fibonacci = 1L # Thanks to Python to handle very big numbers
old1 = 0
old2 = 1
limit = 1000

i = 1


start = time.time() #Start timer for bench
while digits(fibonacci) < limit:
    fibonacci = old1 + old2
    old1 = old2
    old2 = fibonacci
    i +=  1



print "The first term in the Fibonacci sequence to contain %s digits is : %s" % (str(limit), str(i))

print "Calculated in %3.6f seconds" %  (time.time() - start)
```